# Creating MEAN API Route Error

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mean-stack

Hi all I am trying to create an API route as shown below.

```
app.post('/jobs/find', jobs.search);
```

But every time I try to access this endpoint I get this error:

```
"errmsg":{"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"find\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Job\"","name":"CastError","stringValue":"\"find\"","kind":"ObjectId","value":"find","path":"_id"}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means you are using an illegal ObjectId as argument to the Mongoose/MongoDB function you are using in `jobs.search()`. You have to show us `jobs.search()` too, otherwise it's just guessing on our part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the function in a callback like so:

```
app.post('/jobs/find', (req,res,next) => {
    jobs.search()
})
```